# Include in setup excel file

Tags: c#, excel

i'm trying to include in my setup (pubish) an excel file, that is on my bin/debug folder.

[image]

When I click on properties, I have them as **Build Action**: Content and **Copy to output directory**: Copy always.

On my Application files I have:
[image]

my code looks like this:

```
string UDOFileName = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "UDOs.xlsx";

if (System.IO.File.Exists(UDOFileName))
{
    // Do some Work
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("File not found");
}
```

When I run my program it works, but when I create the setup and run my application I get the "File not found" message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running in Release mode? That will cause `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` to point to `bin\Release` instead of `bin\Debug`.

Comment: I'm running on debug mode

Comment: Put a breakpoint in after the string assignment, what value is in `UDOFileName` after it is assigned? Does it have the path that is expected? (i.e. the project folder path, including `bin\Debug`)

Answer (score 0):

St. Pat gave me the idea to switch to **release mode** and I changed the code to

> string UDOFileName = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +
>   @"bin\Debug\UDOs.xlsx";

Now everything is working